# Loading .so files using Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am using JNI to load the *.so files in my Java class.I make a web service call by passing some parameters to the .so file from Java.I have loaded the libraries in the following way.

```
System.load("/home/myserver/libfsdk.so");
```

I have made this as a jar and passed the parameters to the main method.It worked fine.But when i make a web service call to a method and then load the .so using the above code,the libraries are not getting loaded.If the path i have specified is wrong then i might have got UnsatisfiedLinkError exception.The execution stops at the above line without throwing any exception.I have googled it out and spent lot of time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What was the text of the exception?

Comment: I am not getting any exception.The system just hangs when loading the library.

Comment: issue seems somewhere else not in the way you are loading. you can first check whether it is being loaded (can put print trace at the starting point under .so library code) or it hangs before loading

Comment: @vishal_aim I have printed and checked before and after loading .The one under .so library code does not print.

Answer (score 0):

Try without ".so"

```
System.loadLibrary("/home/myserver/fsdk");
```

and without prefix lib in method loadLibrary

Comment: System.load requires the **full path**

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Directory separator should not appear in library name